# bc30451 : Label access issue in VB in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am just beginner in asp.net, so may be missing some basic, but my problem is i am getting following error in my code 
**"BC30451  'TimeLabel' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."**
Please go though the link for my code access:http://s21.postimg.org/glw8ps32f/code_Snippets.png

I have tried to relate with other solution, but no one works.

Comment: What "other solution" did you try?

Comment: Why should we go elsewhere to view an image of the code when you could do what you should be doing and posting the actual relevant code right here?

Comment: i have tried to post here, since it contain html, so its interprets that tag also. (I am newbie so please bare me)

Comment: @mbdevpl i tried to make public deceleration of call instead of protected.

Comment: @titamazon You can post your code, including `<html>` tags. Follow this: https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode

Comment: @mbdevpl ok sir, next time i will keep in mind, now help me regarding my issue. I stucked from last 2 days :(

Comment: @titamazon Well... please also keep in mind that you can edit your own questions. And I recommend doing that because IMHO attaching the code that's causing the problem will help others in helping you. Also, people don't take orders here, so I'm afraid that "now help me" might not make anything go faster for you.

Comment: @titamazon Google your question and you will probably find a lot more examples of why this error occurs. I'm sure one of those answers will help.

Comment: Right, your problem is because the aspx page is declaring 'TimeLabel` and inheriting from `_Default`. `_Default` is trying to access the label which again is declared in a child class. I'm not familiar with ASP.net myself, but that seems to be a problem

Comment: what you have looks ok. The problem is that you likely have OTHER pages that have CodeFile="Default.asp.vb". This will occur if you copyied the file manually. I would remove (or check) for other pages that have ColdeFile pointing to Default.aspx.vb.